# Glass noisy at edges and bottom of objecj

Tags: cycles-render-engine, glass

I have a cup model which I applied subsampling and solidify modifiers. I want to render the object as glass. For that I use just the glass bsdf, with an hdri and single area light (disk) for lighting. Camera focal lenght is set to 100mm, samples to 200 and light bounces increased to 24. Cycles with adaptive sampling and denoise[image] for rendering in Blender 2.93.

The results I get are a bit noisy in the edges and the bottom of the cup. See three rendered images at 512x512. I have tried changing the glass shader adding transparent bsdf with mix shader, and tweaking clamp parameters, etc. as I found in several tutorial recommendations. In all the cases the noise at the edges can't be removed.

I guess I'm missing something but I can't really find what.

Comment: This is just because the light is bouncing around so many times, even a slight variation in direction near the start can result in a totally different path near the end, and thus a different sample color.

Comment: Slightly off topic, but I'd recommend using LuxCore renderer (free) for caustics, glass, etc. renderings. It's more accurate than cycles.

Comment: Actually, 200 samples is not very much when using glass and reflective materials. For most of the time I don't use more either, but I have the _Denoise_ option activated for rendering. It doesn't look like you're using _Denoise_.

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions. I've played a bit more with light bounces with no luck. Increasing num samples to 2000 has improved a bit the scene, but still not good enough. LuxCore gives much better results, however is quite slow.

Comment: @JordiSanchezRiera Did you use _Denoise_? As I said, I hardly ever use more than 200 samples for simple renders... and this is just one single glass object? Can't believe you're not getting a decent result...

Comment: Yes, I used denoise NLM and also OptiX, getting very similar results. The use of denoise does not make really a difference in my setup. The small black and white pixels, in bottom, edges and handle of cup still there after denoise.

Comment: White pixels are most likely reflections of a light source, black pixels are usually when a ray has hit the maximum number of bounces without finding a light, so the ray is reported back as "lost".  Increase glossy bounces under light paths

Comment: I encountered similar problems with other objects, some of them I could solve modifying the topology, but still it seems that the curvy faces generates a lot of noise in the glass bsdf